# In LLVM, can you specify that two different code paths will produce the same result?

Tags: c, llvm, compiler-optimization

I'm writing a C library for an embedded platform, and the platform's firmware has several routines for character output. One of the subroutines is general purpose - you load the ASCII character you want to print into a register, call the subroutine, and the character prints out. A few other subroutines, however, skip the register load and output specific control characters, such as the bell character and carriage return.

In my `putchar()` implementation (which `printf` uses), I might want to use each of these routines for different characters that come in:

```
void putchar(char c) {
    if (__builtin_expect(c == '\n', 0)) call_line_feed_out();
    else if (__builtin_expect(c == '\a', 0)) call_bell_out();
    else call_cout(c);
}
```

When compiling `printf` for general purpose input, I would like LLVM to optimize `putchar()` directly to `call_cout` and skip the branching. However, in cases where LLVM is able to compile everything down to `putchar` calls (such as with constant string prints that are small enough), I would like LLVM to use these special endpoints to save memory.

I imagine that LLVM would naturally do this if it knew that, say `call_line_feed_out()` and `call_cout('\n')` did the same thing, and it would choose the best code path for either. Is this something I can do, or will I need to perform this differentiation further up the line (such as by having `printf` call `call_cout` directly)?

(Note that the bodies of these `call_` functions are `asm volatile` statements that make the firmware calls, and LLVM does not have access to the listings of these calls. If it is an option, though, I do have the listings on hand and *could* provide those to LLVM somehow, so it can make that determination on its own.)

Comment: Try making `void putchar(char c)` a `static inline` function.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart That helps with inlining the call (which the compiler is aggressively doing already), but not with the branching inside. When C compiles `printf`'s call to `putchar`, it's not going to know at runtime which characters are being printed. I would like `printf` to just call `call_cout` instead of wasting cycles on branching each time.

Comment: I think Clang / LLVM these days supports `if (__builtin_constant_p(c) ) { ... }` to let you only do extra conditionals if `c` is a constant after inlining + constant-propagation.  (Older `clang` evaluated `__builtin_constant_p` before inlining, making it basically useless, but I think that's changed to match GCC.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to tell the compiler that it could make a different call instead, but we can achieve the same goal a different way in this case.

**The usual way to special-case only for compile-time constants is with `__builtin_constant_p()`** to test if a variable's value is known at compile time, after inlining + constant-folding.  (Older Clang used to evaluate `__builtin_constant_p()` too early, before inlining, so function args would never be constants, making it somewhat useless except in macros.  But that's since been fixed, making it work [like GCC intended](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fconstant_005fp).)

The `_p` naming of GCC builtins [comes from Lisp](http://www.catb.org/esr/jargon/html/p-convention.html). It's a "predicate" function - it asks a yes/no question and returns a boolean.

```
void my_putchar(char c) {
    if (__builtin_constant_p(c)) {
        // only reached if c is a compile-time constant after inlining
        if (c == '\n') { call_line_feed_out(); return; }
        else if (c == '\a') { call_bell_out(); return; }
    }
    // else runtime variable or a constant that wasn't one of those special cases
    call_cout(c);
}
```

A non-inline definition of `my_putchar` is just a tailcall to `call_cout`.  (It would be even better if we could somehow make the symbol an alias for `call_cout` so execution wouldn't have to bounce through that one-instruction function.)

Or it's just a regular call to `call_cout` when inlined with a non-constant, or with a char other than `'\n'` or `'\a'`.

```
void use_putchar_newline(void){
    my_putchar('\n');
}
```

compiles to just `b  call_line_feed_out` - a tailcall.

```
void use_putchar_test(char *str){
    my_putchar(str[0]);
    my_putchar(str[1]);
    my_putchar(str[2]);
    const char *strconst = "ab\n";
    my_putchar(strconst[0]);
    my_putchar(strconst[1]);
    my_putchar(strconst[2]);
}
```

compiled for AArch64 with [clang on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1AB9U8lJL6yAngGVG6AMKpaAVxYMQAJmkOAMngMmABy7gBGmMQgAMwapAAOqAqEtgzObh7e0onJNgIBQaEsEVGxFphWeQxCBEzEBOnunlwAbOWVqTV1BAUh4ZExcQq19Y2ZrRYjPYF9xQOxAJQWqK7EyOwcAG6oeOgA1KK0tMZorgQQyAh1BwsApNEAQrcaAILbuwdix7QzxlSYmHQxhW53e6Duj2ebx2%2B0OxwiR2BZwgYIhT1eULBexYAE9jPEzpc6sDiHhgBcrsQbntbgB2dEvPZMvZ4Kh7CCmMKuOg2BjGTCqeKYawXGnRAAi93FezAHFuAFZHAxZaQ9hoFgtPoifkE/gCgSCIGiocy9hUlCy2RzjFyeYF%2BYLhedkGLJRKZXLFUwVWqNVr4RVjobja9TebMP6TobkCGXnTJRjXljcfjCZSKdcYzT6Sbmaz2ZzubReVGGMNDAR8Rc/XSGabTQB6Bt7AS0HF7YiYJiXQGWg4shR7JgHVAseJ0TAAWhsbBHZdqglz9b7oqlUo9CqVss1tcjOswesBSPOaI7mAIqwY9we2YTjOXZtoFvzq4l69lm%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%2BjUyApgnPoeBhCtkBLKg8RVGTk4/dEeyTvwLCEK7QtsJOiQ85ELsAOpfLwqAs8QpJYFbRrtE6qT2AwTguE0MTyqQ/gzEUJSDAkSQpAIYzNDnuSpL0mcDBMlixwIXSjEnmTRKnldM9XUyl/0pRDFMBd6OW9Rt3MUStEsdWrOsEhLHzJWkPNIecEOxAXddw53dTeytH1Ggb%2ByuCECQLktQsvDrVoGqkAgXZYFE0c9YNA0jffg1jRNU0zXNEOLctq1tR1SxbYgKDHX2uQSgu0ToDFEAvFokhgBcGiF4OIL03qYAVr9f6Ksga8WIKDcGdMEYwxVngpGKM0bWBVljRgBBcb4zpoTVwxNSYq0ptTWmFV8CMxsCzMmFV2bIE5irP2fMKoCyFkjEWGwKri0ljwaWst5ZfVQcrcm2t1biC1vwQQigVDqDproaIRsjAmzMObS28AbZ21SA7J2Ls3YeyoF7KcvtBD%2B0nEHI4Icw4R1ZtbGOzdPAQAcN3Q26dCjtz0DkPOaQ66F3CVUfuWdDZNyqDXBoUSe4VCrtUVuGdQkJK7qk3J3Q4nl2HvVMeXAJ7FVKu/OeLwABKABZKBewADijgaqwL6l4LeEAd5ECpE1A%2BR8f5LHPkwS%2BlBuq9Tvg/EaRUOCTVINNLgT0Z6VU4J/Nawy5leCqXTD%2B38NqnzDskOwkggA%3D) `-O3 -fomit-frame-pointer`.  (I thought `-fomit-frame-pointer` would be on by default at `-O3` for Linux, but apparently it wasn't.)

```
use_putchar_test:
        stp     x30, x19, [sp, #-16]!           // 16-byte Folded Spill  // save return address and a call-preserved reg
        mov     x19, x0                         // copy str to a call-preserved reg

        ldrb    w0, [x0]           // my_putchar(str[0]);
        bl      call_cout
        ldrb    w0, [x19, #1]
        bl      call_cout
        ldrb    w0, [x19, #2]
        bl      call_cout          // my_putchar(str[2]);

        mov     w0, #97
        bl      call_cout          // my_putchar(strconst[0])
        mov     w0, #98
        bl      call_cout
        ldp     x30, x19, [sp], #16             // 16-byte Folded Reload
        b       call_line_feed_out  // my_putchar(strconst[2]) tailcall
```

So we have no runtime branching for unknown runtime-variable inputs, and we still have dispatch to the special-case function for a constant newline from a string literal.

GCC compiles it about the same.